# Select options disapear when i select item (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a strange case. When i select item as select option items in select disappear. This is happening in both selectors.
This is my controller

```
controllers.addLocationCtrl = function($scope, countriesFactory, provincesFactory){

    countriesFactory.getCountries().then(function(data){
        $scope.countries = data;
        console.log($scope.countries);
    });
    provincesFactory.getProvinces().then(function(data){
        $scope.provinces = data;
        console.log($scope.provinces);
    });
}
```

This are objects for countries

```
[{"id_country":"1","country":"Austria"},
{"id_country":"2","country":"Belgium"},{"id_country":"3","country":"Bulgaria"},{"id_country":"4","country":"Croatia"},{"id_country":"5","country":"Cyprus"},{"id_country":"6","country":"Czech Republic"},
{"id_country":"7","country":"Denmark"},{"id_country":"8","country":"Estonia"},{"id_country":"9","country":"Finland"},{"id_country":"10","country":"France"},{"id_country":"11","country":"Germany"},{"id_country":"12","country":"Greece"}]
```

And this is my HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Country</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="countries"
            data-ng-options="c.id_country as c.country for c in countries"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Province</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="provinces"
            data-ng-options="p.id_province as p.province for p in provinces">
    </select>
</div>
```

When i select one item in select then this happens

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Country</label>
    <select class="form-control ng-valid ng-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" 
     data-ng-model="countries" data-ng-options="c.id_country as c.country for c in countries"><option selected="selected"></option></select>
</div>
```

[image]

Console log shows no errors at all. Am i using data-ng-model wrong way? What might be the couse for this problem. If you need any additional information's please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select an item, AngularJS replaces the content of `countries` with the `id_country` that you have selected. So no countries to show in the `select` tag.

See your issue in this demo:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);
  app.controller("addLocationCtrl", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.countries = [{
        "id_country": "1",
        "country": "Austria"
      }, {
        "id_country": "2",
        "country": "Belgium"
      }, {
        "id_country": "3",
        "country": "Bulgaria"
      }, {
        "id_country": "4",
        "country": "Croatia"
      }, {
        "id_country": "5",
        "country": "Cyprus"
      }, {
        "id_country": "6",
        "country": "Czech Republic"
      }, {
        "id_country": "7",
        "country": "Denmark"
      }, {
        "id_country": "8",
        "country": "Estonia"
      }, {
        "id_country": "9",
        "country": "Finland"
      }, {
        "id_country": "10",
        "country": "France"
      }, {
        "id_country": "11",
        "country": "Germany"
      }, {
        "id_country": "12",
        "country": "Greece"
      }];
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app">
  <div data-ng-controller="addLocationCtrl">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Country</label>
      <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="countries" data-ng-options="c.id_country as c.country for c in countries"></select>{{countries}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Province</label>
      <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="provinces" data-ng-options="p.id_province as p.province for p in provinces">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution:** Replace data-ng-model="**countries**" by other name.

`data-ng-model="currentCountryId"` and `data-ng-model="currentProvinceId"`.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);
  app.controller("addLocationCtrl", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.countries = [{
        "id_country": "1",
        "country": "Austria"
      }, {
        "id_country": "2",
        "country": "Belgium"
      }, {
        "id_country": "3",
        "country": "Bulgaria"
      }, {
        "id_country": "4",
        "country": "Croatia"
      }, {
        "id_country": "5",
        "country": "Cyprus"
      }, {
        "id_country": "6",
        "country": "Czech Republic"
      }, {
        "id_country": "7",
        "country": "Denmark"
      }, {
        "id_country": "8",
        "country": "Estonia"
      }, {
        "id_country": "9",
        "country": "Finland"
      }, {
        "id_country": "10",
        "country": "France"
      }, {
        "id_country": "11",
        "country": "Germany"
      }, {
        "id_country": "12",
        "country": "Greece"
      }];
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app">
  <div data-ng-controller="addLocationCtrl">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Country</label>
      <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="currentCountryId" data-ng-options="c.id_country as c.country for c in countries"></select>{{countries}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Province</label>
      <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="currentProvinceId" data-ng-options="p.id_province as p.province for p in provinces">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: of course :D it makes much more sens now! :D Thank you!